# Backtrader error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'setenvironment'

Tags: python, feed, backtrader

I am new to backtrader, and I have a big problem. I want to start my strategy (just a simple GoldenCross strategy). This GoldenCross.py Script looks like this:

```
import math
import backtrader as bt



class GoldenCross(bt.Strategy):
    params = (("fast", 50), 
                ("slow", 200), 
                ("order percentage", 0.95), 
                ("ticker", "AAPL"))

    def __init__(self):
        self.fast_moving_average = self.bt.indicators.SmoothedMovingAverage(
           self.data.close, 
           period=self.p.fast,
           plotname="50 day moving average")
        self.slow_moving_average = self.bt.indicators.SmoothedMovingAverage(
           self.data.close, 
           period=self.p.slow,
           plotname="200 day moving average")
        self.crossover = self.bt.indicators.crossover(self.fast_moving_average, self.slow_moving_average)

    def next(self):
        pass
```

Now I want to run the strategy with my run.py script. In this script the code looks like this:

```
import os, sys, argparse
import pandas as pd 
import backtrader as bt 
from Strategien.GoldenCross import GoldenCross
import datetime



cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.broker.setcash(100000)

symbol = "AAPL"
path = "/Users/me/Desktop/allgemein/Visual Studio/Stock Data/S&P500 Aktien 1H/" + symbol + ".csv"
stock_prices = pd.read_csv(path)


feed = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=stock_prices)
#(dataname=stock_prices)
cerebro.adddata(stock_prices)

cerebro.addstrategy(GoldenCross)
cerebro.run()
cerebro.plot()
```

Now the visual studio compiler gives me back an **error** called: ***"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'setenvironment'"***.

I don't know what's the problem. Maby the problem is in my csv data.. My Date column looks like this:

```
     Unnamed: 0                      date    close     high      low     open
0              0  2017-01-03T15:00:00.000Z  115.450  115.815  115.400  115.600
1              1  2017-01-03T16:00:00.000Z  115.370  115.670  115.135  115.450
2              2  2017-01-03T17:00:00.000Z  115.470  115.525  115.270  115.365
3              3  2017-01-03T18:00:00.000Z  115.235  115.495  115.235  115.475
4              4  2017-01-03T19:00:00.000Z  115.435  115.445  115.160  115.235
...          ...                       ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
```

But I already tried to convert this date to date time with using :

```
stock_prices['date'] = pd.to_datetime(stock_prices['date']) #object to datetime
```

But this doesn't change the problem either..

Does anyone have a good tip for me?

best regards
Christian

Comment: I have no experience loading tabbed data files. I usually use csv files which can be easily loaded with GenericCSVData found here: https://www.backtrader.com/docu/datafeed/

Answer (score 7):

must adddata feed (not stock_prices)
feed = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=stock_prices)
cerebro.adddata(stock_prices)

to

```
feed = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=stock_prices)
cerebro.adddata(feed)
```

for me this works if you set datetime as index and parse datetime

```
stock_prices = pd.read_csv(path, index_col='datetime', parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: For anyone using Fastquant, this works for data from `get_yahoo_data()`.

Answer (score 0):

Start with removing self from self.bt.whatever... bt is not a member of self here. Additionally you've not called the correct crossover indicator. The name should be camel cased. Try:

```
class GoldenCross(bt.Strategy):
    params = (("fast", 50),
                ("slow", 200),
                ("order percentage", 0.95),
                ("ticker", "AAPL"))

    def __init__(self):
        self.fast_moving_average = bt.indicators.SmoothedMovingAverage(
           self.data.close,
           period=self.p.fast,
           plotname="50 day moving average")
        self.slow_moving_average = bt.indicators.SmoothedMovingAverage(
           self.data.close,
           period=self.p.slow,
           plotname="200 day moving average")
        self.crossover = bt.indicators.CrossOver(self.fast_moving_average, self.slow_moving_average)
```